# Open Web Content with parameter on Domino Web Server

Tags: http, lotus-notes

I have an ExtJS application in my IBM Domino HTTP Server in the WebContent directory.
Since the ExtJS application interacts with Domino server application, I can't switch servers.

Said application's microloader requests for app.json?1393951293124, which throws an error 400 - "Unknown Command".
The timestamp should make sure that I get a fresh copy every time.

The app won't be accessed through internet or proxy servers, only from intranet. Under these circumstances, is it secure to remove the line where the Date is added?
If not, how could one possibly request a fresh copy of app.json from the Domino HTTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `app.json?open&<time stamp>` if you are able to change the call.

Comment: Could you expand on this a little?

Comment: Can you change the way the microloader asks for app.json? If so, then try the format above. It currently fails because Domino expects a certain set of URL parameters as the first parameter. It should work if you can add ?open and then append the time stamp.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't find ?open in the IBM docs.